# Período variável data SQL Server

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Abaixo tenho o seguinte código onde busca em uma tabela todos os dados dentro do período especificado nas variáveis declaradas. Porém, um cliente em específico possui um fechamento de mês diferenciado, no caso, o mês dele inicia-se no dia 26, e termina no dia 25.

Estou tentando fazer as variáveis trazerem este período mas sem sucesso!

No caso, a variavel `@periodoInicial` teria que começar em `2017-07-26` e a variavel `@periodoFinal` em `2017-08-25`, e terminando este período, as variaveis ja se alterassem para `2017-08-26` até `2017-09-25`, é possível fazer isso?

Código:

```
declare @periodoInicial as date,
        @periodoFinal as date
set @periodoInicial = cast(dateadd(mm,-1,dateadd(dd,-day(getdate())+1,getdate())) as date)
set @periodoFinal = cast(dateadd(dd,-day(getdate()),getdate()) as date)

SELECT * FROM productionEnvironmentInvoiceData
where proposalDate between @periodoInicial and @periodoFinal
```

> ***NOTA: ESTOU COM O SQL SERVER 2008***

Comment: não entendi o " terminando este período, as variaveis ja se alterassem para 2017-08-26 até 2017-09-25"

Comment: Na realidade deveria ser criado uma coluna dia_de_fechamento na tabela de clientes, obter este "dia" e com base nele fazer o cálculo.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis por exemplo, o mes neste caso não é do dia 01 até o 30 ou 31, e sim inicia-se no dia 26 e acaba no 25, entende?

Comment: @Motta você diz colocar uma coluna 'periodoInicial' que repita 26 em todas as linhas e outra com 26 'periodoFinal' e seguir o calculo das variaveis dando select nesta tabela?

Comment: não, digo coluna diadefechamento na tabela de empresa o sql ficaria algo como 
SELECT * 
FROM productionEnvironmentInvoiceData  , EMPRESAS
where productionEnvironmentInvoiceData.CODEMPESA = EMPRESAS.CODEMPESA
AND proposalDate between CONVERT(DATETIME, ANO + MES-1 + diadefechamento+1)
                 and CONVERT(DATETIME, ANO + MES + diadefechamento)

Comment: @jvbarsou, só uma duvida, na tabela productionEnvironmentInvoiceData o campo é `Date` ou `Datetime` ? Se for `Datetime`, interessante utilizar do dia 26 ao dia 26, por que sendo a data final 2017-08-26, haverá a questão das horas e minutos.

Comment: Como está sua tabela de cliente?

Comment: @RicardoSouza o campo é `date`

Comment: como assim? @Sorack

Comment: @jvbarsou você pega o dia pelo cadastro de cliente, não é?

Comment: @Sorack se entendi bem oq vc quis dizer, não, na verdadeiro eu seto na variavel mesmo o periodo pois irei fazer uma procedure em especifico para este tipo de cliente. Tanto que esta tabela trata-se de dados apenas deles.

Comment: @jvbarsou você sabe a versão do seu SQL Server?

Comment: @Sorack no caso estou usando o sql server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caso esteja utilizando a versão 2012 ou superior do `SQL Server` o seguinte código irá atender a especificação:

```
DECLARE @dia    INT;
DECLARE @inicio DATE;
DECLARE @fim    DATE;

SET @dia = 26;

SET @inicio = DATEADD(DAY, @dia, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -2));
SET @fim = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @inicio));

SELECT *
  FROM ProductionEnvironmentInvoiceData peid
 WHERE peid.proposalDate BETWEEN @inicio AND @fim;
```

---

Para versões anteriores ao 2012 o código adaptado ficaria assim:

```
DECLARE @dia int;
DECLARE @inicio date;
DECLARE @fim date;

SET @dia = 26;

SET @inicio = DATEADD(day, @dia - 1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())), 0));
SET @fim = DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(month, 1, @inicio));

SELECT *
  FROM productionenvironmentinvoicedata peid
 WHERE peid.proposaldate BETWEEN @inicio AND @fim;
```

---

> [`DATEADD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186819(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Retorna uma `date` especificada com o intervalo `number` especificado (inteiro assinado) adicionado à `datepart` especificada dessa `date`.

---

> [`EOMONTH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh213020(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Retorna o último dia do mês que contém a data especificada com um deslocamento opcional.

Comment: para versão 2008, como posso adaptar o codigo?

Comment: @jvbarsou adicionei para versões anteriores

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente @Sorack, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

> *No caso, a variavel @periodoInicial teria que começar em 2017-07-26 e a variavel @periodoFinal em 2017-08-25, e terminando este período, as variaveis ja se alterassem para 2017-08-26 até 2017-09-25, é possível fazer isso?*

Se quer coletar períodos mensais, considerando-se um período maior de meses, eis uma abordagem. Primeiro deve-se definir o período completo de emissão, que envolve vários meses. O código se encarrega de gerar cada mês, definindo então os valores das variáveis @periodoInicial e @PeriodoFinal, conforme solicitado.

```
-- código #1 v3
--> informe o dia inicial do período completo de emissão (formato dd/mm/aaaa)
declare @MêsInicial date, @MêsFinal date;
set @MêsInicial= convert(date, '26/7/2017', 103);
set @MêsFinal= convert(date, '26/8/2017', 103);

-- variáveis para emissão mensal
declare @periodoInicial date, @periodoFinal date;

-- início do primeiro mês
set @periodoInicial= @MêsInicial;

while @periodoInicial <= @MêsFinal
  begin
  -- calcula o final do mês
  set @periodoFinal= dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, +1, @periodoInicial));
  -- processamento do mês
  SELECT colunas 
    from productionEnvironmentInvoiceData
    where proposalDate between @periodoInicial and @periodoFinal;
  -- próximo início de mês
  set @periodoInicial= dateadd(month, +1, @periodoInicial);
  end;
```